# How to solve out the $event issue in angular application when I'm using and Angular Material and some code customizing it

Tags: javascript, angular, multidimensional-array, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I found an issue in Angular 6 version with that using Angular Material. Anybody can help me to fixed this error of $event.

```html
 ERROR Error: Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "nameValue". Template variables are read-only.
at _AstToIrVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js._AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite (compiler.js:8719)
at PropertyWrite.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.PropertyWrite.visit (compiler.js:7589)
at convertActionBinding (compiler.js:8320)
at prepareEventListenerParameters (compiler.js:17473)
at Object.params (compiler.js:18598)
at compiler.js:18369
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at compiler.js:18369
at compiler.js:17630
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

I didn't use any template variable.
I put it directly in the Html.

```html
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "nameValue". Template variables are read-only. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "nameValue". Template variables are read-only.
    at _AstToIrVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js._AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite (compiler.js:8719)
    at PropertyWrite.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.PropertyWrite.visit (compiler.js:7589)
    at convertActionBinding (compiler.js:8320)
    at prepareEventListenerParameters (compiler.js:17473)
    at Object.params (compiler.js:18598)
    at compiler.js:18369
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at compiler.js:18369
    at compiler.js:17630
    at Array.map (<anonymous>) Error: Cannot assign value "$event" to template variable "nameValue". Template variables are read-only.
    at _AstToIrVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js._AstToIrVisitor.visitPropertyWrite (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:39190:27)
    at PropertyWrite.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.PropertyWrite.visit (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:38060:24)
    at convertActionBinding (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:38791:45)
    at prepareEventListenerParameters (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:47944:23)
    at Object.params (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:49069:20)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:48840:90
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:48840:56
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:48101:83
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
```

Any solution for this

Comment: search your template, you must be having a variable declaration like "let nameValue" or "#nameValue"

Comment: Please always include the relevant code snippet(s), because then we can provide exact answers

Comment: I think that the problem is that you has a error type code, you're using something `event='what ever'`, must be `event=='what ever'` (two equals)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem with Angular 9. I figured out that I had declared a variable like `"let nameValue of values"` and after I did `[(item)]=nameValue` on the Template. The problem was I had assigned `item` to `nameValue` with double-binding. Removing the `()` solved my problem

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you for  this answer, I had the same issue migrating an app to ng9 (stepped approach to ng 12).  The double-binding was indeed my issues as well, and removing the (  )  solved it.  The odd thing was that this only appeared when running tests via "ng test" and not when running the app via "ng serve".  Odd that.